# Unable to connect to cluster from Spring Boot app, getting ConnectionInitException: "Could not reach any contact point"

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

```
Failed to connect to the Cassandra cluster: Could not reach any contact point, \
  make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): \
  Node(endPoint=/192.168.60.24:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=2b19536d): \
  [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: \
  [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request
```

i have test with postman tool to connect with cassandra with springboot Method. But i'm unable to connect. this is the url i'm trying from postman: http://localhost:8080/migration/test/cassandra?cassandraHost=localhost&cassandraUsername=cassandra&cassandraPassword=cassandra

Answer (score 0):

It appears your driver cannot connect to Cassandra at all.  If everything is configured correctly, start by checking the network to ensure you have a route to the host you are connecting to. Also check to see if client encryption is enabled in Cassandra and if you need this for the driver.  Ensure Cassandra is listening on port 9042 as well.  If you can't get it working, show your driver config.

Comment: assuming that cassandraHost is set to 192.168.60.24, this seems fine
Can you telnet or nc to port 9042 from your driver host and get connectivity?

Comment: i can able to connect cassandra cluster on my local machine: 

WARNING: console codepage must be set to cp65001 to support utf-8 encoding on Windows platforms.
If you experience encoding problems, change your console codepage with 'chcp 65001' before starting cqlsh.

Connected to Test Cluster at 192.168.60.24:9042.

Comment: If you have connectivity, then what version of Cassandra and what driver version are in use?  are they compatible? Do you have client auth set up in Cassandra? do you use authorization? is the user/password correct? Does the user have permission to connect?

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted indicates that the Cassandra Java driver used by your Spring Boot app is unable to reach the Cassandra node on IP `192.168.60.24` on CQL client port `9042`.

You need to verify the following:

1. Cassandra is running.
2. Cassandra is listening for client connections on IP `192.168.60.24` and port `9042`.
3. There is network connectivity between your app and the Cassandra node(s).

One thing I noted is that you've specified the Cassandra host as `localhost` in your Postman URL --

```
http://localhost:8080/migration/test/cassandra?cassandraHost=localhost&cassandraUsername=cassandra&cassandraPassword=cassandra
```

If the C* instance is listening for connections on `192.168.60.24`, you cannot use `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`). You need to instead use `192.168.60.24`. Cheers!